# Memory corruption with std::initializer_list

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-corruption

I have memory corruption in this code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::initializer_list<std::string>> lists = {
        {
            {"text1"},
            {"text2"},
            {"text3"}
        },
        {
            {"text4"},
            {"text5"}
        }
    };

    int i = 0;
    std::cout << "lists.size() = " << lists.size() << std::endl;
    for ( auto& list: lists ) {
        std::cout << "lists[" << i << "].size() = " << lists[i].size() << std::endl;
        int j = 0;
        for ( auto& string: list ) {
            std::cout << "lists[" << i << "][" << j << "] = "<< string << std::endl;
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
lists.size() = 2
lists[0].size() = 3
lists[0][0] = text10�j  ����text2H�j    ����text3`�j    ����text4����text5��������q
```

The problem is in `std::initializer_list`. Changing `std::initializer_list` to `std::vector` solves the problem.

The question is why memory corruption takes place with `std::initializer_list`?

Comment: `std::initializer_lists` have their name for a reason. They're supposed to only be used *for initialization*, not long-term storage. That's why they have reference semantics. All your `std::initializer_list`s actually only live until the end of the initialization of `lists`.

Comment: `^^` This comment has been officially accepted by the system as the correct answer to your question. Thank you for using our services!

Answer (score 1):

Because of std::string objects were destroyed before this line:

`int i = 0;`

If std::string has debug output in their destructors and ctors. You will be see something like:
std::string::string 5 times,
std::string::~string 5 times
and after that

lists.size() = 2

Because of initializre_list not contain copy of std::string objects, they (temporary std::string objects0 just created and destroyed before ';'

It is for example like take reference to std::string object
in such expression:

std::cout << std::string("17");

But if you replace std::string with "const char *" in your example all should works, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Storage for initializer list is destroyed after usage, which is before line:

```
int i = 0;
```

Its details are implementation spesific, but it generally creates a dynamic array at construction and this dynamic array is destroyed at destruction.

You can find more detail at [cppreference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)